# How can I boot an Xbox One remotely using Amazon Alexa?

Tags: alexa, wake-on-lan, microsoft-xbox

I've been researching how to control an Xbox One through Alexa, but I can't find a straightforward way to achieve this. A [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/amazonecho/comments/4c1prj/alexa_and_xbox_one_integration_possible/d1elbk4/) suggests using the Blumoo remote, but I'd rather not pay for *more* hardware if I can avoid it.

[This article](http://www.insidegamer.net/2014/07/18/xbox-one-august-update-brings-wake-lan-kind/) from InsideGamer suggests that there is *some* sort of remote control ability:

> Microsoft’s August Xbox One update brings with it a long awaited feature for Xbox owners, the ability to wake your console to automatically download games, addons and DLC when you aren’t in proximity to it.

Is there some form of [Wake-on-LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) I can use, perhaps? I'd be happy with any method to turn it on wirelessly though, even if I have to use something like [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) to trigger it.

Comment: [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiUlpn166LRAhVGKo8KHTgaAOgQFgghMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FSchamper%2Fxbox-remote-power&usg=AFQjCNGxifTIaAde3iXSngUwfK81vaUvQA&sig2=pZAmwNFjNjkpqbg4X9ME5Q) is a link that would help you...

Comment: using some IR module connected to the Iot would trigger. but Hardware is extra..! :)

Comment: unfortunately, the WOL feature is supported only over the LAN!

Comment: I know the Xbox One has an IR blaster to turn other things on, but I think it only accepts wireless/LAN connections for turning it on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know you wrote that you would rather not purchase additional hardware, yet at least this is an option.  You can easily use the Harmony hub, here is how to do it: [Controlling Your Entertainment System with Alexa and the Harmony Hub @ VoiceDesigned.com](http://www.voicedesigned.com/?q=content/controlling-your-entertainment-system-alexa-and-harmony-hub)